# Status de processamento em chamadas Ajax (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Possuo uma aplicação que faz comunicação com o servidor utilizando chamadas ajax com jquery. Porém, em alguns casos, o tempo para o retorno da chamada acaba sendo longo demais. Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de receber uma informação com o status da requisição (em porcentagem), até que esta esteja completa. Abaixo, um exemplo do código utilizado:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",                  
    url: metodo_url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) { 

        console.log("Sucesso: " + result.d);

    },error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log("Erro: " + xmlHttpRequest);

    }
});
```

OBS: Cheguei a encontrar uma forma de retorno da porcentagem do processo da chamada, porém, esta era referente ao upload da informação (útil no caso de envio de parâmetros e/ou arquivos), e não do processamento como um todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe um meio que faz *mais ou menos* o que você quer, mas não poderia ser usado no jQuery.

Veja, o jQuery é, na verdade, uma abstração de um monte de funções do Javascript para tornar a linguagem mais simples e fácil de usar. O `$.ajax` nada mais é do que um objeto `XmlHttpRequest` (o famoso XHR que você pode ler [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)).

O objeto XHR trabalha com estados, ou seja, temos que criar um handler que será chamado toda vez que o estado da chamada AJAX for alterado. Um XHR pode ter os seguintes estados:

- 0: Requisição ainda não iniciada
- 1: Conexão com o servidor estabelecida
- 2: Requisição recebida
- 3: Processando requisição
- 4: Requisição concluída, resposta pronta

Tendo essa informação, você pode fazer uma barra de progresso que flutue de 20% em 20% (já que são 5 estados para 100%). Isto deve ser feito no evento `onreadystatechanged` mais ou menos como no modelo abaixo:

```
var counter = 0

function ajax() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  // Abre a conexão para a página
  xhr.open('GET', '<URL>')

  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    counter += 20
    if (xhr.readystate === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText) // Aqui você tem sua resposta
    }
  })

  xhr.send()
}
```

Este é um meio de fazer.